# Ng2BootstrapModule from ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap

I was using Ng2BootstrapModule with ngx-bootstrap version 1.6.6, when I upgraded ngx-bootstrap to version 3.1.1, Ng2BootstrapModule no longer is recognized. Any help with what replaced this?

Answer (score 0):

All-in-one model is considered bad practice after angular version 4 so it was removed.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta8-2017-11-03